# RecyclerView inside of NavigationDrawer not scrolling

Tags: java, android, xml

I've started a project and in this project I added a RecyclerView inside of NavigationView but for some reason the RecylerView not scrolling.

https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/7/31/d58464f32d8ebb24885b876f81ce2274-full.png

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    tools:openDrawer="end">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/digikala_navigation_drawer_header" android:id="@+id/navigationDrawerHeader"/>
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/navigationDrawerRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/navigationDrawerHeader">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

...

Comment: try using wrap_content for height of your RecyclerView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should change content place with navigationView (navigationView must be last-child)

```
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        tools:openDrawer="end">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
           // Content
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <include layout="@layout/digikala_navigation_drawer_header" android:id="@+id/navigationDrawerHeader"/>
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/navigationDrawerRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/navigationDrawerHeader">

            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

with

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

in your `Recyclerview`.

Comment: @Jakob I'm sorry. I meant Recyclerview instead of RelativeLayout. Try wrap_content in your Recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a** `vertical_recycler_view.xml`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**You have to inflate and add the RecyclerView where ever you want:**

```
public class MyCustomViewGroup extends FrameLayout
{
    public MyCustomViewGroup(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        RecyclerView verticalRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) 
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.vertical_recycler_view, null);
        verticalRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, 
        LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        addView(verticalRecyclerView);
    }
}
```

I hope It helps you!

Comment: Hell xavi jimenz. I have the recycler view in my main_activity.xml and set an adater and layout manager at my MainActivity.java. Can you tell me where exactily I should use this code? Did you mean a nested class inside MainActivity.

Comment: Create de xml for the recycler. Create de class. In your activity you have to create an instance of this class and pass the context.